# only working when manual input value

Tags: javascript

why this code is not working. but when im manual insert value for **var nm2=budi;** its working

```
<div>
Date From: <input id="date1" class='easyui-datebox' style='width:150px'>
To: <input id="date2" class='easyui-datebox' style='width:150px'>
Nama <input id="nama" style='width:150px' class="easyui-validatebox">
<a href='#' id="aaa" class='easyui-linkbutton' iconCls='icon-search'>Cari</a>
</div>
```

and here the javascript

```
var d1=0;
var d2=0;
var nm2=$('#nama').val();

$('#date1').datebox({
    onSelect: function(date){
        d1= date.getFullYear()+"/"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"/"+date.getDate();
    }
})

$('#date2').datebox({    
    onSelect: function(date){
        d2= date.getFullYear()+"/"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"/"+date.getDate();
    }
})

$('#aaa').click(function(){    
    $('#query').datagrid('options').url="getjson.php?&names="+nm2+"&start_date="+d1+"&end_date="+d2;
    $('#query').datagrid('reload');
})
```

Comment: Why isn't the javascript code wrapped in `<script>` tag?

Comment: Have any DOM modifying javascript?

Comment: Among other things, the line var nm2=$('#nama').val(); is being run once on page load before the value of #nama is set. So, you get something like getjson.php?&names=&start_date=...

Comment: yes, im using easyui datagrid

Comment: This is a initial value of input, you should get value in click event.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine this is because you're assigning your value for nm2 when the script loads.  I'd imagine you'd want to assign it when you click your submit.

```
$('#aaa').click(function(){
nm2=$('#nama').val();
$('#query').datagrid('options').url="getjson.php?names="+nm2+"&start_date="+d1+"&end_date="+d2;
$('#query').datagrid('reload');
})
```

That should at least get you on the right track.

Comment: yes i wanna assign the value from input with id=nama when i submit the button, and your code still not working in my case :(

Comment: @kidboy90 Hey, sorry that's not working for you, are your queries going out?  I've put together a [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/cc3vt/) that shows how you would do it in pure JS.

Comment: its working now, sorry i have wrong url="getjson.php?&names= it should be url="getjson.php?names= thx alot guys :D

Answer (score 0):

Why do you declare it outside your function?

If in any case you want to use that var nm2 as a global var, you can do it like this

```
var nm2;

$('#aaa').click(function(){ 
    nm2 = $('#nama').val();
    $('#query').datagrid('options').url="getjson.php?&names="+nm2+"&start_date="+d1+"&end_date="+d2;
    $('#query').datagrid('reload');
})
```

Sorry it's not a complete code, please try it your self.

Comment: No worries mate.. salam kenal!